# What is wrong with this for loop command in MATLAB (excluding an index)

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I am trying to exclude an index within a `for` loop. I can't understand why the following code keeps bringing up an error:

```
for(l=1:Nmax, l~=m)
```

The error is

> Error: File: BARW2Dwithducts.m Line: 76 Column: 24
>   Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.

I don't see how the expression is unbalanced (the code itself works fine and is error free if I just use `for l=1:Nmax`, but this doesn't give me what I need...

Comment: The error is trying to tell you your syntax is incorrect. To skip you would have to check the value inside the for loop with an if statement

Comment: Where did you see this syntax? You can’t just make up new syntax and expect it to work. Please read the [MATLAB documentation page on the for loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html). If the syntax is not described there, it’s not legal syntax.

Answer (score 3):

To skip an index, your typical option is to put the following inside the loop (as the first thing):

```
if (l == m)
   continue
end
```

Another option is to generate all indices, then remove the target one:

```
allInds = 1:Nmax;
allInds(allInds == m) = []; % remove index m.
for l = allInds
...
```

This has a nice advantage that you can clearly see all the indices that will be visited before the loop even starts, and as you start adding extra conditions this one scales much better than a horrible nest of conditions inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

One way to skip the value `m` is to do as follows:

```
for l=[1:m-1,m+1:Nmax]
   % ...
end
```

Note that this will not work if `m-1>Nmax`, as you will visit values larger than `Nmax`.